# getting transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease error in android studio

Tags: android-studio, dependencies

I am getting error while creating sign apk in android studio.

Following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpHeaders.class
```

My dependencies are following:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile project(':wordPayLib')
compile project(':simple-crop-image-lib')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.+'
compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.+'
compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'

compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.24.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'

compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
```

}

I am not using any external jar in libs folder.

Please suggest me how to fix above error.

Thank you.